# Updating epel repo to 6 - epel-release-6-x.noarch conflicts with file from package epel-release-5-x.noarch

Tags: centos, rpm, epel

I am following an epel repo upgrade guide from Centos 5 to Centos 6 here (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/enable-epel-repository/ and http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/epel-issues-centos-6-a-4175424243/), and getting a weird error. How can I solve this?

```
     rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo from install of epel-release-6-8.noarch conflicts with file from package epel-release-5-4.noarch
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo from install of epel-release-6-8.noarch conflicts with file from package epel-release-5-4.noarch
```

Comment: So, are you running CentOS 5 or 6 now? If you are running CentOS 6 then remove the epel-release-5-4 package. Also major version upgrades are not supported in CentOS.

Comment: Thx, I run Centos 6, but the image had a centos 5 repo in the rpm config. I deleted those epel repo files, but I still get this. Perhaps I can flush rpm db somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're sure you're running C6, try `rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`.  That will upgrade the package (ie, replace older with newer) instead of trying to install the two alongside each other.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment, if you are running CentOS 6 then remove the epel-release-5-4 package, or upgrade it as MadHatter suggested.
Either way, major version upgrades are not supported in CentOS and you might run into trouble later on.